# Import a python script in MainFolder to another script in MainFolder/file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I an writing an app to record data given by the user, calculate and print out bills. I have written a script usage.py in MainFolder and want to pull its methods or functions in MainFolder/file/MainFile.py . I have already used the methods or functions in usage.py in MainWin.py
The scripts are in the 3 py extensions are pasted [here](http://bpaste.net/show/S0kvBcniHvEQbgaMCfqu/)

How can I use them in methods in MainFolder/usage.py in MainFolder/file/MainFile.py ?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the folder a package that will allow you to use the methods in either location. But, to give further advice it would make more sense to move the methods that are in usage.py into the MainFile.py from a design standpoint.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to use functions in a top level file in a nested file.

If you make it a module you can use:

```
from some.package.usage import policySize
```

Module documentation:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: thats fine but i have many more folders along with file inside the MainFolder. usage.py is needed in then also. how to deal with that?

Comment: Using modules you can import from files in the above directories just as you would a normal import.  There is a little more to it, but that is explained in the documentation.  But, if you want to use something in useage.py in the directorty below it then it will work as long as it is a module.

So, each folder you would put a ____init____.py in it and then do your importing normally.